# NSLayoutManager Text new line seems to start from bottom of rectangle and go up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, text, nslayoutmanager

```
m_LayoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
m_TextContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];
m_TextStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString: @"Here's to the crazy ones, the misfits, the rebels, the troublemakers, the round pegs in the square holes, the ones who see things differently."];  
[m_LayoutManager addTextContainer: m_TextContainer];
[m_TextStorage addLayoutManager: m_LayoutManager];
[m_TextContainer release];
[m_LayoutManager release];
[m_TextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [m_TextStorage length]) withString: XMajor];
[m_TextContainer setContainerSize: NSMakeSize(75,50)];

NSRange glyphRange = [m_LayoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer: m_TextContainer];
NSRect usedRect = [m_LayoutManager usedRectForTextContainer: m_TextContainer];

[[NSColor brownColor] setFill];
//NSRectFill( NSMakeRect(j - usedRect.size.width/2,y0 - 50 - 5,50,50));

[m_LayoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphRange 
                                 atPoint: NSMakePoint(j - usedRect.size.width/2,y0 - 50 - 5)];
```

What I end up seeing is the text starting from the bottom of the rectangle and going up.  It looks like this when I draw it in view:

```
ferently.
the ones who see things dif
nd pegs in the square holes, 
the troublemakers, the rou
 the misfits, the rebels,
Here's to the crazy ones,
```

I want the text to start from top and go down and I also want the text to word wrap, right now it will start the middle of a word on a new line.  I read about `NSLayoutManager`, `NSParagraphStyle`, and `NSTypeSetter`, but I cannot figure out how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `isFlipped` to return YES in your subclass of NSView.

Comment: Was a pain in the butt, had to rewrite my entire charting code with that fix, but it worked!  Thanks.  I never would have figured that one out.

Comment: I did this without an `NSView` (with a `CGContextRef` and `-graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:flipped:`). In this case, you just set flipped to YES, and then flip it again using a `NSAffineTransform`.